# In Struts2, how to specify static content directory other than /struts or /static?

Tags: java, struts2, struts, static-files

In an existing struts2 project, images are stored in /public/images, js and css are stored in /js/* and /css/* respectively.  Currently they are all loaded correctly by the url `http://testdomain.com/js/test.js`.  However, a "Cache-Control: private" is always added to it.

After my research online, seems like the only way to serve static content is to put them in `/struts` or `/static`.  Is there anyway I can change that?  Struts2 version that is being used is 2.2.1.  I also know that perhaps a custom filter can be used but I do not seem to be able to find some more details on it.

Comment: are you using Apache as your web-server or only tomcat? static content you are talking about are related to the css/images and js files being used by framework itself

Comment: I do the same and "Cache-Control: private" is not added to any of my static content so we'll need more information. Web server are you using?

Comment: Have you read the docs ? http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/static-content.html